# How show data of table based on input parameters asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want search in my asp.net page. In this page user types in a name in a textbox and then selects one value from a combobox that has two values (`ascending, descending`), she/he also must select one choice from a radio button list (`price, add_date, name`).

Now these parameters post to database. What can be stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that shows data of my `Product` table based on these parameters?

My table is `Product` and has these columns: `ID, Name, picture, Price, Added_date`

When user for example types `Camera` in text field and selects `Ascending` and `price`, the result must be a table that show all camera based on their price in ascending order.

I really don't know what can be stored procedure? I'm new to databases. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetProducts
@Name NVARCHAR(100),
@SortOrder CHAR(10) 
AS
BEGIN
IF @SortOrder = 'ASCENDING'
    SELECT ID,[Name],Price,AddedDate FROM Product
    WHERE [Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
    ORDER BY [Name] ASC
ELSE IF @SortOrder = 'DESCENDING'
    SELECT ID,[Name],Price,AddedDate FROM Product
    WHERE [Name] LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
    ORDER BY [Name] DESC
END
```

**And you execute it like this:**

```
EXEC GetProducts @Name='Cam',@SortOrder='DESCENDING'
```